# H2 datastore EXTREMELY slow? (NOT Really! See EDIT)

Tags: performance, datanucleus, h2

I just tested the H2 datastore (with Datanucleus 2.x)

The performance is VERY slow. 1/3 of Postgres and 1/10 of MySQL (aprox.)

I was very pleased by the "specs" but i cannot see them in "real usage".
http://www.h2database.com/html/performance.html

Is there any performance tuning that i might be missing?

**EDIT:**

H2 is not SLOW. Is one of the fastest RDBMS i have tested to date!

**I need help explaining WHY i need to CONNECT to the database using the WEB MANAGER (H2 console) to get the fantastic speed of this DB engine...** I accidentally tested my app when CONNECTED through the H2 WEB console "et voilá", problem solved.

Why?

Comment: What version of H2 do you use? What is your database URL? What is you test case?

Comment: i'm using the latest release of H2 Version 1.2.143 (2010-09-18), with h2-1.2.143.jar JDBC connector. My test case is a FULL featured (covers almost all java types and relations) datastore (of course, dependent of Datanucleus persistence engine)

Comment: Did you profile your test to find out what particular feature is slow? Usually it's just one that is responsible for 90% of the problem. A simple way to profile is using java -Xrunhprof:cpu=samples

Comment: As below, since you cannot even connect reliably to the web interface I fail to see the relevance of DataNucleus, or your app or anything. Try a simple JDBC program perhaps, using the JDBC URL. i.e basic debugging

Comment: Please take a look at my EDIT.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, H2 closes the database when the last connection is closed. If your application closes the only connection after each operation, the database is opened and closed a lot, which is quite slow.

There are multiple ways to solve this problem:

- use a connection pool, or
- keep a 'sentinel' connection open for as long as the application runs, or
- use delayed database closing by appending ;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=10 to the database URL

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I also got a similar one on the H2 Google forum. That's exactly the problem!

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you have a host lookup problem; 5 seconds is a typical DNS timeout.